# Abstract algebra

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

**Question**

> Prove that $a=a^2$ in a group if and only if $a=e$

**Attempt**
      Suppose that $a^2=a$ such that $a\in G$ , that is $(G, *)$
      Then $a*e=e*a=a$ 
       Implies that  $ae=ea=a$
      Now suppose that $a≠e$ 
      Since $a^{-1}a=aa^{-1}=e$
      Then $a(aa^{-1})=e$
           $aa=e$
           $a^2=e$
      Now suppose that $a=e$ 
      Then $a=a^2$

Please help me with your solution so that I would know that what I have done is correct.

Comment: The proof looks very circular and doesn't actually make the conclusion that you want. You have unnecessary steps (you say that $ae = a$ implies $ae=a$...?), you don't use the assumption that $a \ne e$, and you have at least one incorrect conclusion. After the step $a(aa^{-1}) = e$ (which is wrong), you get $aa = e$, which doesn't follow. So I don't really see that you've ever used an assumption that $a = a^2$. For a successful proof, perhaps assume $a = a^2$ and multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: You can add mathjax to improve your post. See the edits to learn how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks bh can you at least help me with a brief intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every group $G$ we have the cancellation law. So we can "cancel" an $a$, by multiplying with $a^{-1}$ on both sides of the equation $a=a^2=aa$, to obtain  that $a^{-1}a=a^{-1}aa$, which says that $e=a$.

Comment: So can I start by answering it by:                             supposing that aa^-1£G. Since a^-1 is an inverse element in a we have that aa^-1=a^-1a=e